# Custom repository implementation for Neo4j doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

This is similar to what is discussed at [Unable to use two Neo4j Instances with Spring boot/Spring data neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154146/unable-to-use-two-neo4j-instances-with-spring-boot-spring-data-neo4j/52049006#52049006) but I don't have two databases. I have downloaded the spring-data neo4j sample java application from the git repo and want to execute a dynamic query instead of executing a static query via repository interface.

I am facing an issue of null transaction manager.

Here's my interface :

```
public interface SearchRepositoryCustom {

    Iterable<Movie> searchByCriteria();
}
```

Here's my custom repo impl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class SearchRepositoryImpl implements SearchRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Movie> searchByCriteria() {

        String query = "MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m,r,a LIMIT 10";
        return sessionFactory.openSession().query(Movie.class, query, Collections.emptyMap());
    }

}
```

Here's my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "movies.spring.data.neo4j.repositories")
public class Neo4jPersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.data.neo4j")
    public Neo4jProperties neo4jProperties() {
        return new Neo4jProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration userConfiguration() {
        return neo4jProperties().createConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(userConfiguration(), "movies.spring.data.neo4j.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
    }
}
```

Since I have only one TransactionManager and One SessionFactory (as I have only one Neo4j instance) I don't need to name the beans separately.

I am seeing the following exception :

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.TransactionManagerException: Transaction is not current for this thread
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.rollback(DefaultTransactionManager.java:86) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.rollback(AbstractTransaction.java:65) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.rollback(BoltTransaction.java:61) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.close(AbstractTransaction.java:144) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:379) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1007) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:793) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at movies.spring.data.neo4j.repositories.SearchRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d2631bcd.searchByCriteria(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at movies.spring.data.neo4j.controller.MovieController.advGlobal(MovieController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Even if I actually go ahead and declare the name of the beans and mark the method transactional by specifying the name of the transactionManager, I still get the same error consistently.

Java version : 1.8

### neo4j version : 3.4.6

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52053208/1547989) is right. I'd like to add the two options we have here. We provide an injectable `Session` that is bound to the current thread and is integrated with Springs transactions. Just auto wire that instead of the `SessionFactory` and you're good to go with your solution. Please note that I'm using constructor injection as recommended throughout all Spring projects:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
class SearchRepositoryImpl implements SearchRepositoryCustom {
    private final Session session;

    public SearchRepositoryImpl(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<ThingEntity> searchByCriteria() {
        String query = "MATCH (t:ThingEntity)  RETURN t LIMIT 10";
        return session.query(ThingEntity.class, query, Map.of());
    }
}
```

I have used another domain to create a concise example project, but the idea stays the same.

For a simple use case like that I fully agree with Gerrit and would use the `@Query` annotation on a declarative Spring Data Neo4j repository like this:

```
interface ThingRepository extends Neo4jRepository<ThingEntity, Long> {
    @Query("MATCH (t:ThingEntity)  RETURN t LIMIT 10")
    public Iterable<ThingEntity> searchByCriteria();
}
```

The usage is the same, as demonstrated here:

```
@Component
class ExampleUsage implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final ThingRepository thingRepository;

    private final SearchRepositoryCustom searchRepositoryCustom;

    public ExampleUsage(ThingRepository thingRepository,  SearchRepositoryCustom searchRepositoryCustom) {
        this.thingRepository = thingRepository;
        this.searchRepositoryCustom = searchRepositoryCustom;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        this.thingRepository.save(new ThingEntity(1));
        this.thingRepository.save(new ThingEntity(2));

        var things = this.searchRepositoryCustom.searchByCriteria();
        things.forEach(System.out::println);

        things = this.thingRepository.searchByCriteria();
        things.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

You'll find the complete application as a gist: [Use Spring Data Neo4js injectable OGM Session](https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/6a95921c293faa8d3da68caa37c8598e). I have used Java 10 instead of 8 as we approaching EOL for Java 8, but that doesn't change the repository implementations. Apart from that, tested with Spring Boot 2.0.4, Spring Data Kay and OGM 3.1.0.

Edit: In regard to the comment: The injectable session is a proxy. The field itself is final, but the proxy opens sessions as needed and then delegates to it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works as well. SearchRepositoryImpl in my case is a Spring managed Repository, wouldn't there be separate sessions for different requests, or one "final" session is fine?

Comment: I've added the answer I gave you via email as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up Neo4j-OGM‘s `SessionFactory`/`Session` and the `@Transactional` support of Spring (Data Neo4j). The latter will create a new transaction of which the OGM code is not aware and tries to create a fresh transaction.

If you use Spring Data Neo4j you can also define the query within your entity repository with a `@Query` annotated method.

The other solution would be to remove the `@Transactional` annotation in your service layer and create it manually if you plan to execute multiple operations (Not needed for one because OGM will create a transaction implicit if it does not exist).

Comment: Thanks that worked! I can't use the query annotation as it needs static queries, my use case makes dynmaic queries all the time, so I have to resort to my own implementation and cant take help of Spring Data much.